# how to pass input field value in resolver in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to fetch data before a component loads so I am using `resolver`. But I need to pass the `input` field value in the resolver, then hit the service with that value.  Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uhjq3a?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest.resolver.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TestResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    // id = 1
    return this.testService.getConfiguration(1);
  }
}
```

Currently I am passing the hardcoded value `1` in this function `getConfiguration(1)`. I want that whatever a user enters in the input field, needs to be passed

```
sclick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.sfrm.value.name);
    this.router.navigate(['next']);
}
```

Here I am fetching the value of the input field: `console.log(this.sfrm.value.name);`

**Service**

```
getConfiguration(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/'+id)
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          console.log(response);
          return response.data;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
}
```

Comment: Value should be part of your routePath otherwise you won't get the value if open this page directly in browser

Comment: @yurzui how I will acheive using routepath ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzumsk?file=src/app/test.resolver.ts See also https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#description

Comment: @yurzui . not working..when i type `1` in inputfied it not getting response

Comment: can you please check

Comment: http://take.ms/orKu9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178991/discussion-between-user944513-and-yurzui).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxurk5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: i think you are doing in `next` anchor link I want to do on `submit button click`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtgxft?file=src/app/hello.component.ts